# Is there a neater way to get the first occurrence of something?

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I have a list which contains a number of things:

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'foo', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'bar']
```

I'd like to get the first item in the list that fulfils a predicate, say `len(item) > 2`. Is there a neater way to do it than itertools' dropwhile and next?

```
first = next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: len(x) <= 2, lista))
```

I did use `[item for item in lista if len(item)>2][0]` at first, but that requires python to generate the entire list first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> lista = ['a', 'b', 'foo', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'bar']
>>> next(i for i in lista if len(i) > 2)
'foo'
```

Comment: Note that the next function was added in 2.6.  If you need compatibility with 2.5 or 2.4 then use `(i for i in lista if len(i) > 2).next()`